# bootstrap table ions on specific row

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I can successfully display bootstrap table from JSON output however I cant work out how to populate a button on the last column to appear in each row

```
<table class = "table table-hovergrey" data-search="true"  data-toggle="table" data-url="php/data.php" data-height="auto">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="ID">ID</th>
                    <th data-field="Name">Name</th>
                    <th data-field="Age">Age</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
   // DB Credentials goes here
        $db_name  = 'dbName';
        $hostname = 'hostname';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password'; 
// connect to the database

 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

// a query get all the records from the users table
        $sql = 'select ID,Name,Age from PEOPLE ';

// use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good    practice
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // fetch the results into an array
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: The data on the table is being populated from a PHP file where I am getting the data from an SQL database and storing the reuslt in JSON output

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment - but I'm not sure how you are populating the table - perhaps you have a custom directive `data-url` ?

Here is an standard example of grabbing JSON data via `$http`, from an Angular controller (normally you would do http calls in a service, but for the sake of demo..).

The HTML is templated and uses `ng-repeat` to create the table rows. This way you have complete control over the markup, and can create `<button>`'s easily. Here is a working example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/TheFoot/pen/bVdrxQ

Comment: Whoops! I could have sworn this was tagged angular :) Ignore me then.. maybe this is useful for someone who wants an angular solution!!